# r: NbClust() very unreliable / buggy?

Tags: r

I am running `NbClust()` on many different dataframes (i.e. different data, different dimensionality). In most cases it works fine but in some it produces weird errors which seem to be due to some computational bug within some of the indices that `NbClust()` computes.

This is what my code looks like

```
library(NbClust)

NbClust(df, distance="euclidean", min.nc=3, max.nc=5, method = "complete")
```

This is the **error** I get

```
Error in if ((resCritical[ncB - min_nc + 1, 3] >= alphaBeale) &&
(!foundBeale)) { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

another error which I am coming across very often is the following

```
Error in if ((res[ncP - min_nc + 1, 15] <= resCritical[ncP - min_nc + 
 :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Has anyone ever encountered similar problems? Or does anyone know why `NbClust()` is so unreliable? Any workarounds?

Data looks as follows

```
df = structure(list(Rate = c(-0.161, -0.519, 1.163, -0.781, -0.755, 
2.252, -0.206, -0.796, -0.803, 1.444, -0.652, -0.541, -0.759, 
-0.309, 0.945, -0.202, -0.449, 0.551, -0.774, 0.993, -0.434, 
-0.604, -0.571, -0.545, -0.722, -0.696, -0.678, -0.512, -0.759, 
2.857, 0.145, -0.206, -0.689, 0.514, 2.373, -0.659, 0.628, 0.2, 
2.746, -0.781, -0.704, 2.019, -0.826, -0.051, 0.034, -0.693, 
-0.047, -0.571, -0.335, -0.073), Losses = c(-0.142, 4.327, 5.004, 
-0.293, -0.293, -0.293, -0.191, -0.293, -0.293, -0.293, 1.044, 
0.151, -0.276, -0.293, -0.293, 0.004, -0.024, 0.151, -0.293, 
0.223, -0.293, -0.293, 0.089, -0.293, -0.27, -0.293, -0.293, 
-0.293, -0.293, -0.287, -0.03, 0.26, -0.293, -0.223, -0.293, 
-0.293, -0.293, 0.066, -0.293, -0.293, -0.293, -0.215, 0.086, 
0.086, -0.522, -0.518, -0.497, -0.522, -0.516, -0.518)), .Names = c("Rate", 
"Losses"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

A former unanswered question regarding the same problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856635/r-error-for-nbclust-call-when-deploying-it-within-for-loop-error-in-if)

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? Without having sample data that reproduces this problem, it's going to be very difficult to diagnose and fix.

Comment: I had the same problem once. I chose to manually exclude the problematic indices in the argument `index` of the function.

Comment: @agenis, that is great to hear that I am not the only one to have this problem. So do you still remember which indices you excluded to make it work? And do you know why `NbClust()` is behaving so strangely/ unreliable?

Comment: @Andrie, ok, please find my edits above in the description of my question. I would be very thankful for any kind of advice

Comment: @Andrie -since you seem to be one really experienced stack overflow users - do you think the question is worth of putting a bounty on it? I really would like to get behind what is causing the error...

Comment: Make it minimally reproducible first. Add all the necessary library() calls. Run your code in a clean session and ensure the error happens.

Comment: @Andrie, thank you, I edited my code, now it show be reproducible, do you have any advice?

Comment: I think you should file a bug report with the authors. Simplify your code even further.  All you need to reproduce is `dat <- as.data.frame(df.combos[8]); NbClust(dat, distance="euclidean", min.nc=3, max.nc=5, method =  "complete")`. The error occurs because with 4 clusters the NbClust code can't compute the `pf()` value in line 1546 of the function.

Comment: @Andrie, thank you! I have never filed a bug report before, is there any good tutorial/ template on how to do this?

Comment: Try index parameter, eg., index="kl"